# amazon gamecircle login not working

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, amazon-gamecircle

I'm trying to get the Amazon GameCircle to work for leaderboards and achievements.

Here's what I did:

1. I followed the instructions on how to create a game configuration by extract the md5 hash from the keystore. (I only have one keystore)
2. I used the game manifest provided by the unity gamecircle package and replaced the package name.
3. I downloaded the api_key.txt and placed it in the assets folder.

and I have security profile attached.

GameCircle works using the apk when I install it directly, but doesn't work when downloaded through the amazon app store.

Is there anything I forgot or anything else I could try?

here's the logcat messages regarding gamecircle:

```
D/GameCircleClient(21312): SDK Version: 2.4.3
D/com.amazon.identity.auth.map.device.utils.MAPLog.PII(21312): Extracting verison incremental:<obscured>
D/com.amazon.identity.auth.map.device.utils.MAPLog.PII(21312): Incremental version '%s' was in invalid format.:<obscured>
D/com.amazon.identity.auth.device.authorization.api.AmazonAuthorizationManager.PII(21312): AmazonAuthorizationManager:sdkVer=2.0.1 libVer=3.5.1:<obscured>
I/com.amazon.identity.auth.device.authorization.api.AmazonAuthorizationManager(21312): Options bundle is null
I/com.amazon.identity.auth.device.appid.AbstractAppIdentifier(21312): getAppInfo : packageName=com.Senshu.HanabiParty
I/com.amazon.identity.auth.device.appid.AbstractAppIdentifier(21312): getAppInfoFromAPIKey : packageName=com.Senshu.HanabiParty
I/com.amazon.identity.auth.device.appid.AbstractAppIdentifier(21312): Finding API Key for com.Senshu.HanabiParty
I/com.amazon.identity.auth.device.utils.ThirdPartyResourceParser(21312): Attempting to parse API Key from assets directory
I/com.amazon.identity.auth.device.appid.APIKeyDecoder(21312): Begin decoding API Key for packageName=com.Senshu.HanabiParty
I/com.amazon.identity.auth.device.appid.APIKeyDecoder(21312): getKeyParts for packageName=com.Senshu.HanabiParty
D/com.amazon.identity.auth.device.appid.APIKeyDecoder.PII(21312): APIKey:<obscured>
I/com.amazon.identity.auth.device.appid.APIKeyDecoder(21312): verifySignature for packageName=com.Senshu.HanabiParty
I/com.amazon.identity.auth.device.appid.APIKeyDecoder(21312): verifySignature Sha256 for packageName=com.Senshu.HanabiParty
I/com.amazon.identity.auth.device.appid.APIKeyDecoder(21312): verifyPayload for packageName=com.Senshu.HanabiParty
W/com.amazon.identity.auth.device.appid.APIKeyDecoder(21312): Failed to decode: No value for appsig
W/com.amazon.identity.auth.device.appid.APIKeyDecoder(21312): Unable to decode APIKEy for pkg=com.Senshu.HanabiParty
E/GameCircleClient(21312): Unable to read api key.  GameCircle requires an api key to be included in 'assets/api_key.txt'.  GameCircle will not initialize.
E/GameCircleClient(21312): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid API Key
E/GameCircleClient(21312):  at com.amazon.identity.auth.device.authorization.api.AmazonAuthorizationManager.<init>(AmazonAuthorizationManager.java:133)
E/GameCircleClient(21312):  at com.amazon.ags.api.AmazonGamesClient.initialize(AmazonGamesClient.java:144)
E/GameCircleClient(21312):  at com.amazon.ags.api.unity.AmazonGamesClientProxyImpl$1.run(AmazonGamesClientProxyImpl.java:68)
E/GameCircleClient(21312):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
E/GameCircleClient(21312):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
E/GameCircleClient(21312):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
E/GameCircleClient(21312):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6837)
E/GameCircleClient(21312):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/GameCircleClient(21312):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
E/GameCircleClient(21312):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
E/GameCircleClient(21312):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
E/Whispersync(21312): Whispersync client has not been initialized.  Please call AmazonGames.initialize()
E/WS_WhispersyncClientProxyImpl(21312): Whispersync client is null. Cannot set event listener. Please call initialize for AmazonGames.
W/ActivityManager( 3517): getRunningAppProcesses: caller 10605 does not hold REAL_GET_TASKS; limiting output
I/Unity   (21312): AmazonGameCircle: GameCircleManager - serviceNotReady
I/Unity   (21312):  
I/Unity   (21312): (Filename: ./artifacts/generated/common/runtime/UnityEngineDebugBindings.gen.cpp Line: 37)
I/Unity   (21312): 
I/Unity   (21312): Amazon GameCircle Service is not ready
I/Unity   (21312):  
I/Unity   (21312): (Filename: ./artifacts/generated/common/runtime/UnityEngineDebugBindings.gen.cpp Line: 37)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar error where the APIKeyDecoder could not parse my application signature. It fixes by upgrading the login-with-amason-sdk.jar to the latest version manually since they have not published maven coordinates yet. Also notice that now they dont use md5 signature, not even sha1, they using sha256.